# Customizing the UV editing header

Tags: interface

Is it possible to rearrange elements in the UV editing header? Specifically I would like to move the active UV map drop down menu to the left of the default position.
[image]

Comment: It's not exactly related, but a simple workaround could be to click `RMB` on the header and select *Header* > *Collapse menus* menu entry. This will minimize at least some space so UV map dropdown to be not so far away